# VBA script for grouping columns

Tags: vba, excel

I've come across Stackoverflow many times when I've been looking for excel VBA scripting answers, but I've come up to a wall with my searching for an answer to my problem.

I have data which I need to sort, but it needs to be row grouped first, otherwise the sorting takes away the conformity of the info.

I want to group using info on just 1 column, and have found VBA scripts which do what I want except that they group 1 row to many. (if that makes sense)

i have info a little like

```
a            b             c              d
Revise       blank cell   info           info
blank cell   blank cell   info           info
blank cell   blank cell   blank cell     blank cell
Revise       blank cell   info            info
blank cell   blank cell   info           blank cell
Revise       blank cell   info           info
```

etc etc

I want to group the top 3 rows, then the next 2.
but the only VBA script I found looks down the column for the word 'revise' but then groups the cells above the word revise, not below

I hope all that makes sense
thanks for any help

BTW, I dont really have any knowledge of programming, other than what I've gained through running some macros on other projects. Hopefully I wont need telling like a 5 YO, but may need some explanations of any code specific terms

I got this VBA script which works as I described

```
Option Explicit 
Sub Macro2() 
    Dim rData, rCel As Range 
    Set rData = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    With rData 
        On Error Resume Next 
        .Rows.Ungroup 
        .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 
        On Error Goto 0 
    End With 
    For Each rCel In rData 
        If rCel = "END" Then Exit For 
        If rCel <> "Revise" Then 
            Rows(rCel.Row).Group 
            rCel.EntireRow.Hidden = True 
        End If 
    Next 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty non-VBA solution, as you say you are not overly familiar with VBA.

Add a column to the right of your data, which will hold a new index that tracks each time 'Revise' is listed in column A. Starting in A2 and copied down, this will look as follows [you may need to hardcode the first entry as 1]:

```
=if(A2="Revise",A1+1,A1)
```

This will create a column which increases by 1 each time there is a new "Revise". Then just select your entire data block, right-click, and Sort by your new index column.